# Div disappears when page scrolls

Tags: jquery, html, css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ud6hejm6/

I was asked to develop a website for a videogame tournament. If you open the fiddle, you will find a preview of the page. There is a div in the middle as you can see (with this code):

```
<div class="middle teko" id="mezzo">
 <span style="color: purple">EndGame</span><span style="color: yellow">TV</span> &nbsp; + &nbsp; World Cup
</div>
```

I set in the css the property:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

In this way the user can't scroll down the page. By the way, when you click in the div (`id="mezzo"`), the page scrolls down thanks to this code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#mezzo').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });

    $('#back').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });

  });
```

The `id="back"` is the id of the div shown when the page scrolls down.

**The Problem**

If you run that jsfiddle, you will see that everything works perfectly except for the fact that, when the page scrolls down, the central div (the EndGameTV + World Cup one with `id="mezzo"`) remains in the middle of the screen.

Although it has set `position: absolute;`, it doesn't stay where it is but it behaves like I set `position: fixed;`.

Do you know why the div remains on the center of the screen instead of staying where it is when the page scrolls?

What I see in the home:
[image]

What I see when I scroll
[image]

This is the link to the real page: http://www.mkworldcup.com/test.php

Comment: I don't get it because it doesn't scroll when I clicked the middle, thus I can't  trigger the problem

Comment: I have just edited the main post. To me the page scrolls when I click on the middle div

Comment: Your problem is still not replicable in fiddle..

Comment: http://www.mkworldcup.com/test.php This is the page in my server if needed, I really have no idea

Comment: I'm clicking the middle one and still not scrolling.

Comment: It scrolls in my case using firefox and his real link.
On jsfiddle nothing scrolls.

I can't find the button with the id "back" where is it, to test and so on...

Comment: Setting the body height to be 1500 pixels lets the scroll code on `mezzo` work. [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/ud6hejm6/2/). That said, the div _does_ appear when it scrolls....?
On Chrome, your actual site doesn't scroll either.

Comment: Just a heads up. This doesnt work on Chrome. It works on FireFox

Comment: Is there any solution for Chrome? Or do I have to find out another way?

Comment: I dont think you should use `scrollTop()` to position the scroll position when you have `overflow: hidden`. If you remove the `overflow: hidden` does it work as expected?

Comment: The reason behind this is that even though you set it to absolute it will only reacts to the viewable content on your body which has `overflow:hidden` therefor, whether you scroll the content, its will still be at the middle. Its like you are moving a camera with a text in the middle.

Comment: http://www.mkworldcup.com/test.php -> Now it works! I removed the overflow: hidden. Thank you @Jackson!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is add a parent div to your first whole page content

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   
    $('#mezzo').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });

    $('#back').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });
    
  });
```

```css
.background {
   background-color: #232323;
  }
  
  .background1 {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    background-color: #222;
  }
  
  .teko {
    font-family: 'Teko';
    font-size: 30px;
   }

  .background2 {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    background-color: #333;
  }

  .background1:hover, .background2:hover {
    background-color: #545454;
  }

  html, body {
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .fullscreen, .content-a {
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .not-fullscreen, .not-fullscreen, .content-a, .fullscreen.not-overflow, .fullscreen.not-overflow, .content-a {
    height: 50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding: 0px;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  .content-a {
 display:table;
    padding: 0px;
  }

  .content-b {
 display:table-cell;
    position:relative;
 vertical-align:middle;
 text-align:center;
    padding: 0px;
  }

  body{
    margin:0;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:28px;
    line-height:100px;
 color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
  }

  section {
 background:#9ed100;
  }
  
  .infobutton {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 20px;
   left: 20px;
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 40px;
   border-radius: 100%;
   -moz-border-radius: 100%;
   -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
   background-color: #0099CC;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   text-align: center;
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
  }
  
  .mkboards {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 20px;
   right: 20px;
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 40px;
   border-radius: 100%;
   -moz-border-radius: 100%;
   -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
   background-color: #FF9900;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   text-align: center;
  }
  
  .welcome {
   position: fixed;
   top: 20px;
   width: 200px;
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 40px;
   color: #222;
   border-radius: 10px;
   background-color: #D8D8D8;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
   opacity: 0.5;
   text-align: center;
  }
  
  .middle {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   height: 40px;
   width: 300px;
   line-height: 40px;
   margin-top: -20px;
   margin-left: -150px;
   color: #222;
   border-radius: 10px;
   background-color: #D8D8D8;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
   opacity: 0.5;
   text-align: center;
  }
  
  .middle:hover {
   opacity: 1.0;
  }
  
  .welcome:hover {
   opacity: 1.0;
  }
  
  .infobutton:hover {
   background-color: #33ADD6;
  }
  
  .mkboards:hover {
   background-color: #FFAC30;
  }
  
  a:link, a:visited { text-decoration: none; color: #FFF; }
```

```html
<div style="height: 100%; position: relative;">
    <div class="not-fullscreen background1" data-img-width="1600" data-img-height="1064">
        <a href="/mk8/"><div class="content-a">
            <div class="content-b">  
             <img src="/images/mk8.png" alt="Mario Kart 8 - World Cup" />
            </div>
        </div></a>
    </div>
      
    <div class="not-fullscreen background2" data-img-width="1600" data-img-height="1064">
        <a href="/mkw/"><div class="content-a">
            <div class="content-b">
             <img src="/images/mkwii.png" alt="Mario Kart Wii - World Cup" />
            </div>
        </div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="middle teko" id="mezzo" onclick="document.getElementById('mezzo').visibility = 'hidden';">
     <span style="color: purple">EndGame</span><span style="color: yellow">TV</span> &nbsp; + &nbsp; World Cup
    </div>
</div>


<div id="endgame" class="fullscreen" style="background-color: #222;" data-img-width="1600" data-img-height="1064">
    <div class="content-a">
        <div class="content-b">
         <div style="margin: auto; width: 98%;">
          <img id="back" src="http://i.imgur.com/jPsBznl.png" alt="EndGameTV" style="max-width:100%; max-height: 100%;" onclick="document.getElementById('mezzo').visibility = 'visible';" />
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="welcome.php"><div class="welcome teko" style="left: 20px;">
   Welcome
</div>
</a>

<a href="staff.php"><div class="welcome teko" style="right: 20px;">
   Staff
</div>
</a>

<a href="/endgame_rules.pdf" target="blank"><div class="infobutton">
 <div class="content-a">
  <div class="content-b">  
   <img src="/images/qm.png" alt="?" />
  </div>
 </div>
</div></a>

<a href="http://mkboards.com/forums/" name="welcome" target="_blank"><div class="mkboards">
 <div class="content-a">
  <div class="content-b">  
   <img src="/images/qm.png" alt="?" />
  </div>
 </div>
</div></a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/53u4kqt0/

Comment: you don't need a parent div, you just need to change the div to the correct position in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is, that the position of your div is calculated from the position of `<body>`.
when you scroll your content, your `<body>`-position stays the same, so does your div.

solution: change the position of div#mezzo to appear after div.content-b and it will work. This way its at the correct position in the DOM tree.
no additional parent div needed.

your code would look like:

```
-snip-

<div class="content-b">
    <img alt="Mario Kart 8 - World Cup" src="/images/mk8.png">
</div>
<div id="mezzo" class="middle teko" onclick="document.getElementById('mezzo').visibility = 'hidden';">
    <span style="color: purple">EndGame</span>
    <span style="color: yellow">TV</span>
      +   World Cup
</div>

-snip-
```

Comment: I solved the problem by myself. I didn't edit the entire code, I just remove the overflow: hidden; from the body.

Comment: you can leave the overflow, i included a solution for you in my answer.